# mysql stored procedure syntax error at line 9

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter //

create PROCEDURE usp_AlterIsCanceled (p_requestid longtext)

BEGIN

    update requests
    set IsCanceled=1
    where id=p_requestid

end
//

delimiter;
```

> /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'end' at line 9 */

Answer (score 1):

add semicolumn ;

```
DELIMITER $$

create PROCEDURE usp_AlterIsCanceled (p_requestid longtext)

BEGIN

    update requests
    set IsCanceled=1
    where id=p_requestid;

END $$

delimiter;
```

Comment: Congrats for reaching 1000 group!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Thanks but still miles to go miles to go :-)

Comment: replace // with $$